# No method error_messages selenium and capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, capybara-webkit

When using capybara-webkit I have come across the issue of selenium not having an `error_messages` method, although, the documentation for `capybara-webkit` says that I should be able to access it through `page.driver.error_messages` once my flag on the `scenerio` is set with `:js => true`. However, trying to access it, it throws:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `error_messages' for #<Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0xc501fc0>
```

and I have tried to access the messages using:

`page.should_not have page.driver.error_messages`

I have also tried:

`page.should_not :have_errors`

as well as:

`page.should_not have_errors`

but with not avail.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that `error_messages` is a method included in the `capybara-webkit` driver. It is not available for the `selenium-webdriver` driver.

Based on the exception you are getting, you are using the `selenium-webdriver`. By default, Capybara uses selenium-webdriver when `:js => true` is specified.

You likely want to change your `javascript_driver` to use `:webkit` (as mentioned in the usage documentation - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit).

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Comment: Where to add this line?

Comment: @Lokesh, you can place this line at the start of your setup (after you have required Capybara).